# Use of javascript in Tor browser

Tags: anonymity, security, javascript

The java script is blocked on a Tor browser but we can not sign up on many sites with a javascript turned off. From somewhere I have heard that java scripts can reveal our real IP address and hence put our use of Tor browser useless.
My question is, if one signup on some site using Tor browser but with a javascript enabled,  is there any chance of leaking the client's actual IP address?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you need the javascript turned on to sign in to a website, your biggest problem is not javascript, your biggest problem is signing in. By signing in you are revealing who you are!!! Of course, you may use a pseudonym to sign in, but even using pseudonym, you are not anonymous any more. You are pseudo-anonymous. Now you should be real careful not to associate your actual name with your pseudonym through any means. For example, the style you write may reveal some information about you. What you write is also reveal some information about you. What Websites you visit reveal some information about you. If you let something slip, your anonymity maybe over and your pseudonym maybe linked to your real identity. In short, you have a bigger problem now than the javascript being turned on. Having said that, The javascript being turned on is one vector to attack and de-anonymise you, albeit, an important one. But remember, it is one vector among many vectors that can be utilized to de-anonymize you. Anonymity is difficult, specially if you continuesly use Tor to visit many different websites and you do not isolate each of these visits by for example, starting with new identity for each website you visit or even better having a new and unique instance of Tor for each website you visit.

By default The Tor browser enables javascript. Thus, you should have no problem to sign in or log in to many sites. Folks have an option to manually disable the javascript to enhance their anonymity. In your case, since you like to sign in or log in to some sites you should stick in with default Tor browser settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and definitely those precautions are worth considering but you have not answered the question yet which is how to deal with websites need java script to log in and sign up using tor browser?

Comment: @Torlearner, Dear Torlearner, The answer is edited to include additional information about your comment.